# How to merge changes from two branches and test before committing to trunk?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk, svn-merge-reintegrate

i've got work in two branches and one depends on changes in the other, i.e. I want to test both branches combined before I go ahead and commit trunk to the repository.
what I tried is to --reintegrate branch A into branch B (with the intention that I can commit branch B and then intgrate those combined changes into trunk for testing) but I got this:

```
user@jpax-build07:~/src/branch/B$ svn merge --reintegrate ^/branch/A 
svn: E160013: '/svn/NextGen/!svn/rvr/25347/branch/A' path not found
user@jpax-build07:~/src/branch/B$ svn info 
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/user/src/project
URL: https://svn-server:8443/svn/branch/B
Relative URL: ^/branch/A
Repository Root: https://svn-server:8443/svn/project
Repository UUID: e326255c-0818-144b-bcb2-52792ac9bef0
Revision: 25685
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: user
Last Changed Rev: 25662
Last Changed Date: 2019-10-29 09:30:06 -0700 (Tue, 29 Oct 2019)

user@jpax-build07:~/src/branch/B$ svn up 
Updating '.':
At revision 25685.
user@jpax-build07:~/src/branch/B$
```

Why does it not let me do this plus what's this `'/svn/NextGen/!svn/rvr/25347/branch/A' path not found`? Is this because the branches did not both exist at some revision in the past? 
How do I do this done?

Comment: I'm a little confused by these two lines: `URL: https://svn-server:8443/svn/branch/B` and `Relative URL: ^/branch/A`  How is that possible?  Maybe this is causing your path not found error?

Comment: "In Subversion 1.6, a new caret (^) notation was introduced as a shorthand for “the URL of the repository's root directory”. For example, you can use the ^/tags/bigsandwich/ to refer to the URL of the /tags/bigsandwich directory in the root of the repository. " from http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html

Comment: I know that. I was referring to the fact that the full URL ends with `/branch/B` and the relative ends with `branch/A`

Comment: I wanted `branch/B` to be the merge target for `/branch/A` where I could do the testing from, you know... so that changes made to trunk in branch A can be merged and tested along with the changes made in branch B....

Comment: Perhaps there is something I don't understand about SVN. If you are in the A directory, both the full URL and the relative URL ends with `branch/A`; if you are in the B directory, both end with `branch/B`.  So, what state, or what directory are you in, where each URL ends with a different directory?

Comment: If you want to merge branch A into B, I would think you would be in the B directory (where both URLs end with B) when you execute the `svn merge ^/branch/A` command. You can try typing in the full URL (instead of the shortened version) and see if that works.

Comment: Also, I recommend you update to SVN 1.8 or later if you haven't. Then you no longer have to worry about reintergrate vs normal merges, or need to stop using a merged branch.

Comment: @DavidSugar my client is `version 1.9.3 (r1718519)` - I did not know that `--reintegrate` is no longer required... :o as for merging: yes, in the original post, the working directory is `branch/B` and I'm attempting to merge updates from `branch/A` into it but I still get the `svn: E160013` error saying `'path/25347/branches/A'` path not found